# int main() and void main() which one is faster?

Tags: c++

I am just interested, there is one guy, who is saying that if void main() works in some compiler then it is faster than int main(). Is this true or just bs.

Edit: Okay people, I am a first-year uni student I don't know stuff deeply, it just my lector said that void main() is wrong, but another guy said that it is correct and way better if the program compiles, just tell me, this is bs or not ?. Is it stupid to use void main() or not?

Comment: Any time difference is going to be irrelevant compared with process overhead.

My vote: bs.

Comment: I would recommend you tell said person about our [good C++ book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  Sounds like they need to get reacquainted with the language.

Comment: `void main` doesn't compile for me, so `int main` is faster.

Comment: If valid, `void` main would be faster by one instruction (depending on the processor and the compiler optimization setting).  In most assembly language implementations, the return value is placed into a register and the program returns to the operating system.  You would be eliminating the instruction to place the value in a register.  We're talking on the order of nanoseconds here.  Also, this is after your program has finished, so is the savings negligible?

Comment: I think the question is not about "the difference can be negligible" or not. It can be a nice opportunity (for me) to discover why `void main()` is not compiled and which differences there are between the two implementations. Quite possible that the solution can be found by looking in the generated assembly code...when `void main()` is compiled of course

Answer (score 7):

`void main()` is not valid standard C++. Don't ever do that. Simple as that.

All valid C++ programs *must* return an integer from `main`, indicating a success or failure code to the Operating System.

And as far as performance goes, copying (or not) a single integer value takes *nanoseconds* (if even that much), so that's completely irrelevant.

The exception is a *freestanding* implementation.

Comment: You have to be careful here, `void main()` is perfectly okay for *freestanding* systems (embedded chipsets) which normally cannot take arguments and the entire environment is implementation defined. (you are 100% correct for *hosted* environments) [Freestanding and hosted implementations - C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/freestanding)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, see the link I posted.

Comment: @David Right, but I assume OP is not writing a OS kernel or other similar *freestanding* application. Hosted is a fair assumption I think.

Comment: No, dings and I wasn't criticizing, I was just pointing out that there are circumstances were `void main()` are fine (I've been bitten by this before as well). For all your embedded devices, etc.. they need not even have `main()`. I was sure that the section of the standard on [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/), was gospel, but I was schooled on there being a caveat to every rule `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, add your comment as an answer! I think it adds important information. Or you can edit the answer already present

Answer (score 4):

```
int main()
```

or

```
int main(int, char**)
```

Are the only 2 valid entry points for standard C++, `void main()` is nothing.

Comment: Well, visual studio doesn't care if the main is void or int. so what is going on?

Comment: @NameLessAlien VS gives a clear warning **warning C4326: return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'void'**.

Comment: @NamelessAlien Just because a compiler compiles a program does *not* mean that it is valid. C++ has this novel failure mode where asking a compiler "is this a program?" has false positives. Read up on Undefined Behaviour.